# GWT - get Text from the textbox after enter is pressed doesn't work

Tags: java, gwt

In my code I create the textboxes for some words of the text
here is a piece of code

```
for (String word : text){
            if(word.equals("space")){   
                textbox = new TextBox();
                textbox.addKeyDownHandler(new EnterKeyHandler());
                panel.add(textbox);
                ...
}}
```

It works fine, the textboxes appear on the screen.

then I have this code to handle the user input

```
 private class EnterKeyHandler implements KeyDownHandler {

        public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) { 
              if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) { 
                  Window.alert("enter" + textbox.getText());
                 List.add(textbox.getText()); //adds the word to an array 
              }
        }
 }
```

Here I have the problem that when the user insert something and presses enter, `textbox.getText()` has no text. And the program stops here.

Comment: Try textbox.getValue().

Comment: I added  textbox = (TextBox) event.getSource(); and it is better now!

Comment: Yes, it's not clear from your code which textbox you are referring to.

Comment: You can also use the onBlur event

Comment: @Alex you should add (and accept) an answer yourself with the solution you found, so others can see it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since I have many textboxes, I have to use `textbox = (TextBox) event.getSource();`

so it worked fine

```
 private class EnterKeyHandler implements KeyDownHandler {

    public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) { 
          if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) { 
             textbox = (TextBox) event.getSource();
              Window.alert("enter" + textbox.getText());
             List.add(textbox.getText()); //adds the word to an array 
          }
    }
```

}